# Increase the size of data sent through HTTP POST request in Django

Tags: python, django, http

I want to send around 3MB of data using HTTP POST request in Django to a server. I am setting stream=True while sending the request. Is there any other way that I should try to increase the size of the data I am sending? It is not a file post request.

Comment: HTTP POST request size is limited by server (and I think browsers also). There isn't much you can do if server has limited post size to 200KB.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size), it defines maximum size in bytes that a request post can be.

But as gitblame mentioned in a comment, this restriction may come from server-side settings, rather than the application itself. You should check your server's configuration.